# Как автоматически сформировать правильную ссылку?

Tags: ссылки

Подскажите, какой алгоритм лежит в формировании этих ссылок? Каким образом они формируются? Дело в том, что для разного IP одна и та же ссылка на тот же контент выглядит по-разному. Это нужно для правильного проигрывания видео на моем сайте.

Вот ссылки на 1 и тот же контент, но они разные. Причем для одного и того же IP ссылка всегда постоянна и не меняется, как мне их правильно формировать?

> 93.170.135.2/video/ed2cb8276e966aebf9c6ba3a8ed4d79b/Hobbit.Nejdannoe.Puteshestvie.2012.flv
> 93.170.135.2/video/d1a3e776b84facd2e7680c936a26bdeb/Hobbit.Nejdannoe.Puteshestvie.2012.flv
> 93.170.135.2/video/491c8cf28adfbdbc783af5814da66cf6/Hobbit.Nejdannoe.Puteshestvie.2012.flv 188.75.223.43:80 
> 93.170.135.2/video/b26fb497b00d87331eb5edf37d72e5d7/Hobbit.Nejdannoe.Puteshestvie.2012.flv 193.232.106.50:3128
>
> `188.75.223.43:80 - это хост, с которого посещал
> 93.232.106.50:3128 - это хост, с которого посещал`

Comment: /video/md5(что-угодно)/blabla.flv. С неверной стороны подошли к решению. Вы же откуда-то получаете правильную ссылку.